# How to open a second PDF in the same instance of Foxit?

Tags: vba, excel, foxit

I want to use Excel to open two PDFs in Foxit PhantomPDF, so that they open as tabs in the same instance of Foxit.  I have set Foxit as my default PDF viewer, and I'm running the following VBA:

```
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="T:\PDFs\doc1.pdf", NewWindow:=False
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="T:\PDFs\doc2.pdf", NewWindow:=False
```

However, this opens two Foxit windows, each with a single tab, where one has `doc1.pdf` and the other has `doc2.pdf`.  How can I make sure that they will both open in the same instance?

Comment: Acrobat has an object model just like excel. It has open and openinwindow as part of the acroavdoc (and acropddoc). Press f2 in VBA editor, add adobe acrobat, then view it's methods.

Comment: @D.Ddgg, thanks, but I'm using Foxit, not Acrobat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by replacing the `FollowHyperlink` with a `Shell` call as follows:

```
Shell """C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit PhantomPDF\Foxit PhantomPDF.exe"" " & _
      """T:\PDFs\doc1.pdf"""
Shell """C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit PhantomPDF\Foxit PhantomPDF.exe"" " & _
      """T:\PDFs\doc2.pdf"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening Preferences in your PhantomPDF installation and uncheck "Allow multiple instances" under Documents.